# Manipulating ScalingFunctions for several Plots inside Table is working, but not working inside ParallelTable

Tags: plotting, manipulate, list-manipulation, parallelization

I've encountered a problem I can't make sense of:

I'm combining the `ListPlot` of a HPLC chromatogram (called bgcorrected in this case) with a `Table` of `Plots` of Gaussian fits (the function fit with peaks being the gaussians expected value) . With `Manipulate` I added a `SetterBar` to change the scaling of the Plots with `ScalingFunctions`. This works perfectly fine with `Table`, however I get the error message

> Plot::sclfn :  The scaling function FE`scaling$$128 cannot be used to scale coordinates.

when using `ParallelTable` for performance reasons.

The working code with `Table`:

```
Clear[scaling];
Manipulate[
 Show[{ListPlot[bgcorrected, ScalingFunctions -> scaling, 
    PlotRange -> All, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}], 
   Table[
    Plot[fit[[m]][x], {x, 
      Normal[peaks][[m]][[1]] - 5*\[Sigma] /. 
       fit[[m]]["BestFitParameters"], 
      Normal[peaks][[m]][[1]] + 5*\[Sigma] /. 
       fit[[m]]["BestFitParameters"]}, 
     ScalingFunctions -> scaling], {m, Dimensions[Normal[peaks]][[1]]}
    ]}], {{scaling, {Sqrt, InverseFunction[Sqrt]}, 
   "plot scaling"}, {None -> 
    "linear", {Sqrt, InverseFunction[Sqrt]} -> "sqrt", 
   "Log10" -> "log"}, ControlType -> SetterBar, Appearance -> "Row"}]
```

Interestingly, `ParallelTable` works fine when I input the value for `ScalingFunctions` by hand, e.g. `"Log10"` or `{Sqrt,InverseFunction[Sqrt]}`.

Does anyone have an idea why `Table` is working in this case, but `ParallelTable` is not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the subkernels do not know about the definition of `scaling`, since it is only defined in the main kernel. You can set `scaling` to be a shared variable, meaning that once the value is changed in the main kernel, it will be automatically synchronized across all subkernels. Since `scaling` is in your case a local variable, this has to be done inside `Manipulate`, for example via the `Initialization` option:

```
Manipulate[
    ParallelTable[
        Plot[Exp[-(x - m)^2], {x, -1, 8}, ScalingFunctions -> scaling],
    {m, 1, 4}],
    {{scaling, {Sqrt, InverseFunction[Sqrt]}, "plot scaling"}, 
    {None ->  "linear", {Sqrt, InverseFunction[Sqrt]} -> "sqrt", "Log10" -> "log"}, 
    ControlType -> SetterBar, Appearance -> "Row"}, 
    Initialization :> SetSharedVariable[scaling]
]
```

Comment: Thank you very much, sir. This works like a charm and is educational for future uses of parallel computation.